# How to make a GIF by using multiple plots of arrays?

Tags: julia

I want to make simulation of wave packet in free space in Julia and for this purpose I need to store every plot, plotted using arrays, in a frame and then to show it in the form of a simulation of 15 seconds. I have written code for these plots but dont know how to make simulation in which previous line of plot doesn't show and only shows a wave like simulation.

enter code here

```
function gauss(x, xo)
    exp(-k * (x - xo) ^ 2)
    end
y = zeros(100,15)

k =1000
xo = 0.3
for j = 1:2
    x = 0.0 
    for i = 2:99
        y[i, j] = gauss(x, xo)
        x = x + 0.01
        end
    xo = xo + 0.1
end
y
function z(i, n)
     2 * (1 - (r ^ 2)) * y[i, n] - y[i, n - 1] + (r ^ 2) * (y[i + 1, n] + y[i - 1, n])
end
r = 1
mat= zeros(100,15)
for n = 2:14
    for i = 2:99
        y[i, n+1] = z(i, n)
    end
end
y
using Plots

plot(i=1:100,y[:, 1:15])
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to combine plotting with an animation (hopefully this is what you mean). In that case you can use an `@animate` macro:

```
using Plots
x = 0:π/100:8π
anim =  @animate for v ∈ 0:π/20:2π
    plot(x, sin.(x .+ v), legend=false)
end
 
gif(anim, "myanim.gif", fps = 15)
```

[image]

Comment: Sir actually I need to show the simulation of my the plots which I have plotted in my codes. Just run my written code in the question and look these plots and then i need help to create their simulation. Your answer is just a simulation of sin function.

Comment: The goal of StackOverflow is to present minimal working example problems and get technical solution for them. Please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If you need code review please try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/